# What do "sins" imply here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Of the two, for a guy who’s overweight and out of shape, pants will tend to cover a greater wealth of **“sins”** than even the longest shorts.

Can "sins" in this context be construed as excess fat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an oblique reference to a passage in the bible:

> Above all, keep loving one another earnestly, since love **covers a multitude of sins**. (*1 peter 4:8*)

The expression is often used to refer to a broad category of things- often, but not always, negative things. In this case, it could refer to flab, skin folds, sagging flesh, wrinkles, cellulite... all of the above and more.